# Horizontal translate with mouseenter, mouseleave function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make some texts translated horizontally when I hover the mouse in the list. In this case, I want ".java1" translate when I hover to "#java".

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#java").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(".java1").transition({
      x: "+=70"
    }, 10);
  });

  $("#java").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(".java1").transition({
      x: "-=70"
    }, 10);
  });
});
```

```css
@media (min-width:601px) {
  .quarter {
    width: 24.99999%!important;
  }
  .third {
    width: 33.33333%!important;
  }
  .twothird {
    width: 66.66666%!important;
  }
}

p {
  color: #757575!important;
}

ul {
  text-align: left;
}

li {
  color: #333333!important;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 17px;
  padding-right: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  height: 30px;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 750px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

.box-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: #009688;
  padding: 5px;
}

.content {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: auto;
}

.center {
  text-align: center!important;
}

.round-xlarge {
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.teal {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #009688!important;
}

.hover-white:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #fff!important;
}

.margin-right {  
   margin-right : 16px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-container">
    <p style="text-indent: 5px;" class="java1">public</p>
    <p style="text-indent: 5px;" class="java1">static</p>
    <p style="text-indent: 5px;" class="java1">void</p>
    <p style="text-indent: 5px;" class="java1">main</p>
    <p style="text-indent: 5px;" class="java1">(String[] args)</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="third center">
    <div class="center">
      <ul>
        <p><i class="fa fa-asterisk margin-right teal-text"></i>My Skill Set</p>
        <li class="round-xlarge teal hover-white" style="width : 23%" id="java">Java</li>
        <li class="round-xlarge teal hover-white" style="width : 43%">Spring MVC</li>
        <li class="round-xlarge teal hover-white" style="width : 28%">HTML5</li>
        <li class="round-xlarge teal hover-white" style="width : 23%">CSS</li>
        <li class="round-xlarge teal hover-white" style="width : 40%">Javascript</li>
        <li class="round-xlarge teal hover-white" style="width : 28%">jQuery</li>
        <p>...................................................</p>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <p><i class="fa fa-globe margin-right teal-text"></i>Language</p>
        <li class="round-xlarge teal hover-white" style="width : 30%">English</li>
        <li class="round-xlarge teal hover-white" style="width : 38%">Indonesia</li>
        <li class="round-xlarge teal hover-white" style="width : 26%">Korea</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The boxes are hiding in minus margin and I want it to appear after hovering mouse in #java.

However the boxes are unmoved. I can't point it out what's wrong with the script actually? Please help and thank you!

Comment: .transition is not a jQuery function. You have .animate, but I guess you're trying to use http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ ? You need to include it somewhere as you've done with jQuery: `<script src="http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Hana, I've sent you example code that you can run, but to see class `.java1` actually move open example in full screen

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `css` method in jQuery and target `transform` css property, I'm sending you example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#java").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(".java1").css('transform','translateX(-70px)');
  });

  $("#java").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(".java1").css('transform','translateX(70px)');
  });
});
```

```css
@media (min-width:601px) {
  .quarter {
    width: 24.99999%!important;
  }
  .third {
    width: 33.33333%!important;
  }
  .twothird {
    width: 66.66666%!important;
  }
}

p {
  color: #757575!important;
}

ul {
  text-align: left;
}

li {
  color: #333333!important;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 17px;
  padding-right: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  height: 30px;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 750px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

.box-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: #009688;
  padding: 5px;
}

.content {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: auto;
}

.center {
  text-align: center!important;
}

.round-xlarge {
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.teal {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #009688!important;
}

.hover-white:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #fff!important;
}

.margin-right {  
   margin-right : 16px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-container">
    <p style="text-indent: 5px;" class="java1">public</p>
    <p style="text-indent: 5px;" class="java1">static</p>
    <p style="text-indent: 5px;" class="java1">void</p>
    <p style="text-indent: 5px;" class="java1">main</p>
    <p style="text-indent: 5px;" class="java1">(String[] args)</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="third center">
    <div class="center">
      <ul>
        <p><i class="fa fa-asterisk margin-right teal-text"></i>My Skill Set</p>
        <li class="round-xlarge teal hover-white" style="width : 23%" id="java">Java</li>
        <li class="round-xlarge teal hover-white" style="width : 43%">Spring MVC</li>
        <li class="round-xlarge teal hover-white" style="width : 28%">HTML5</li>
        <li class="round-xlarge teal hover-white" style="width : 23%">CSS</li>
        <li class="round-xlarge teal hover-white" style="width : 40%">Javascript</li>
        <li class="round-xlarge teal hover-white" style="width : 28%">jQuery</li>
        <p>...................................................</p>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <p><i class="fa fa-globe margin-right teal-text"></i>Language</p>
        <li class="round-xlarge teal hover-white" style="width : 30%">English</li>
        <li class="round-xlarge teal hover-white" style="width : 38%">Indonesia</li>
        <li class="round-xlarge teal hover-white" style="width : 26%">Korea</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```